# PHPMailer executing around 2 seconds

Tags: php, phpmailer

I was following PHPMailer tutorial and some tutorials in Internet but I still can't make execution less than 2 second. On many website it says it shouldn't take more than 0.4s. I tried it from my local machine and from AWS machine. Execution time same.

```
class BatchMailer {
    private static $mail;
    private static $initialized = false;

    private static function initialize() {
        if (self::$initialized)
            return;

        self::$mail = new PHPMailer;
        self::$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
        self::$mail->isSMTP();
        self::$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        self::$mail->Port = 587;
        self::$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
        self::$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        self::$mail->Username = '***';
        self::$mail->Password = '***';
        self::$mail->SMTPKeepAlive = true;
        self::$mail->setFrom('***@gmail.com', 'Title');
        self::$mail->isHTML(true);
        self::$mail->AltBody = 'Please use an HTML-enabled email client to view this message.';
        self::$initialized = true;
    }

    public static function setSubject($subject) {
        self::initialize();
        self::$mail->Subject = $subject;
    }

    public static function setBody($body) {
        self::initialize();
        self::$mail->Body = stripslashes($body);
    }

    public static function sendTo() {
        self::initialize();
        self::$mail->clearAddresses();

        $recipients = array(
            '***@gmail.com' => 'Person One'
        );

        foreach($recipients as $email => $name) {
            self::$mail->AddCC($email, $name);
        }

        self::$mail->send();
        return;
    }

    static function test() {
        self::setSubject('subject');
        self::setBody('body');
        self::sendTo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SMTP is often slow, especially when things like greetdelay/[tarpitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarpit_(networking)) are used as anti-spam measures. 2 seconds is not that slow - the SMTP spec allows for timeouts of 10-20 **minutes**! It's really unsuited to real-time use, i.e. during a web page submission, but that doesn't seem to stop many trying to use it that way. To maximise performance you can install a local mail server to use as a relay, or hand off your message send to a separate process that doesn't mind waiting for a while, for example by submitting using an async ajax request from your page so the user is not blocked from doing other things.

If you're sending larger volumes of email it's important to use a relay and SMTP keepalive while submitting it. I have no trouble sustaining over 200 messages/second with PHPMailer.

Nice class BTW - tidier than most of the things I see on SO! `$initialized` is not needed - just check whether `self::$mail` is set instead.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Can you suggest any local mail servers that I can use with PHP?

Comment: Any will do, but postfix is probably the easiest to set up. Others are exim, sendmail, haraka, qmail.

Comment: I have used sendgrid mail service , they provide a SMTP api which sends the mail as a API call they have provided the php sdk for that as well! try it,  felt that was pretty quick.  https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/php.html

Comment: @Synchro, for example I will set up postfix and make it use gmail. Phpmailer will use postfix and I will try send email. Will it give fast respond cause postfix will take care of it? Or I still will be waiting when postfix will send it through google. Sorry if I don't really understanding how is it working...

Comment: You will submit it to your local mail server, which will be very fast, and then your mail server will deliver it when it can. It will also take care of things like retrying if initial delivery fails, so it should be more reliable too. PHPMailer is not an MTA, so it lacks such features.